# Sed - unknown option to `s'

Tags: bash, sed

I execute a `sed` command in my script:

```
sed -i "${1}s/${2}=.*/${2}=${REPLY}/" $3
```

this is the echo:

```
sed -i 13s/log4j.appender.ROOT2.File=.*/log4j.appender.ROOT2.File=/app/TET/log.log/ /applis/DIAPASON/diapason1/conf/log4j.properties
```

My error:

`sed: -e expression n°1, character 61: unknown option for`s`'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have multiple `/` characters inside the `$REPLY` variable, which is confusing `sed`.

You can choose an alternate delimiter for the `s///` command in most versions of `sed`, so if this were me, I'd try something like:

```
sed -i "${1}s|${2}=.*|${2}=${REPLY}|" $3
```

This replaces the `/` for sed with `|`, so that the `/` in `${REPLY}` are (hopefully) not interpreted by `sed`.

Comment: *"...in most versions of `sed`"* — actually, *any* version of Sed that is [POSIX compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) can use *any* character other than a newline or a backslash as a delimiter for the `s` command.

Answer (score 2):

Use any character as a s command delimiter, Please find following example

```
sed -Ei "s|$k|$j|g" filename.txt
```