# Pass a linux variable into oracle script

Tags: linux, bash, sed, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to pass mount_point details in my oracle script.

I am able to pass integer variable using below code but not able to send
mount point details in oracle script:

```
sed "s/@@pqr@@/$space/g" tablespace_extend.sql |
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba"
                                                             
BEGIN
space:="@@pqr@@";
dbms_output.put_line(space);
END;
/
```

When I am using same code to pass mount point details, it is not working. it returns this error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s', mount_point = /u08/dbname/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sed - unknown option to \`s'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91630/sed-unknown-option-to-s). You may also be interested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/315749 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059/315749.

Comment: For clarity, can you also please add the content of your `$space` variable to your question? Is it `mount_point = /u08/dbname/`?

Answer (score 1):

try the following as I assume your variable contains special character `/` used as delimiter which is breaking the sed command:

```
$ space="/u08/dbname/"
$ sed "s:@@pqr@@:$space:g" tablespace_extend.sql
BEGIN
space:="/u08/dbname/";
dbms_output.put_line(space);
END;
```

I just switched the sed delimiter to `:` character.

more on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-insert-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed

Comment: Hi Roman,
Its working!
Thanks

Comment: good to be of help :)